# hide one part of JSplitPane in Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jsplitpane

Here is my situation, i want to implement a sidebar on the right side of a JFrame. The sidebar is hidden in default, appear if i click a button.

In order to hide the sidebar, I set the divider location of the JSplitPane with a very large value, say 10000. It works properly in normal java application. Also, i set the setResizeWeight of the JSplitPane to 1.0.

However, if i run it in a applet, the sidebar appear a little bit on the right when i resize the JFrame.

How can i hide the sidebar even when i resize the JFrame? Any idea would be welcome.
ps. i need it done in java 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the JSplitPane wider than the parent by the thickness of the split bar? The JSplitPane should be clipped by the parent container so you don't see the split bar until you want to at which time you can size the pane equal to the parent size and position the split bar position.